# How can I get the custom post title?

Tags: php, title

I need to get the title from my custom post but its showing from my default post. here is my code. please help.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, `echo get_the_title( $slide );`
the_title(), or get_the_title() will not work here.

Answer (score 0):

It's not inside any custom loop, so `the_title();` function won't work here for your custom post. It will go find the post from main query. Try `echo get_the_title($slide);`.

Comment: thanks a lot bro

Comment: If it worked, please select as correct answer. Thank you.